# Use PHP and oci_bind_by_name to pass a list of values to Oracle

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I have a list of numbers I wish to bind or pass to this Oracle SQL query.

```
SELECT
    ad.lastname, ad.name, a.cc cc, sum(a.qt) qt
FROM a, ad
  where ( ad.ci in (:idList) or (:idList is null)) 
  and ad.ci (+) = a.ci
  And A.Type = 'R'
  And A.Cc In ('SIDI','SIND','RSU')
```

Is it allowable to use the command oci_bind_by_name to bind :idList with a string containing a list of Ids? Could be seen as a string that seralizes the Ids?

Example:

It seems unfeasible "just" because the serialized list is not part of SQL syntax. Any ideas to reach my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with a string (unless you want to tokenize your id list with SQL).

oci_bind_by_name requires a string in this case.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but oci_bind_by_name will only accept a string as a bind parameter. `bool oci_bind_by_name ( resource $statement , string $bv_name , mixed &$variable [, int $maxlength = -1 [, int $type = SQLT_CHR ]] )` [http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php)

Comment: Also i'm pretty sure that all bind placeholders must be unique. `:idList) or (:idList`